# Python pandas DataFrame: Transfer data from dictionary to a right cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Can you please tell me how to transfer data from a dictionary to a table using cross-matching? For example, there is a dictionary where each project has its own set of components and there is a table where columns are projects and rows are components.

I need to take each project in the dictionary and check each component in the table. If there are such components in the project, then put a `X` in the right cell.

Components are not unique, they can be repeated in other projects. Projects and components have different numbers.

**Example:**

```py
project_components = {'Project_1': ['component_1', 'component_2', 'component_3', 'component_4'], 
'Project_2': ['component_2', 'component_3'], 
'Project_3': ['component_3', 'component_4'], 
'Project_4': ['component_2'], ...}
```

`Template.csv`

| **Component / Project** | Project_1 | Project_2 | Project_3 | Project_4 | Project_N →→→ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| component_1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_3 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| component_N ↓↓↓ |  |  |  |  |  |

**Outcome:**

| **Component / Project** | Project_1 | Project_2 | Project_3 | Project_4 | Project_N →→→ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| component_1 | x |  |  |  |  |
| component_2 | x | x |  | x |  |
| component_3 | x | x | x |  |  |
| component_4 | x |  | x |  |  |
| component_N ↓↓↓ |  |  |  |  |  |

I know about `iterrows()` but don't understand how to combine it with loop over dictionary and put the value to right cell and save it to CSV.

```py
def read_csv():
    data = pd.read_csv("Template.csv") 
  
    for row in data.iterrows():
        print(row)

read_csv()
```

Added `Template.csv`

```
Component / Project; Project_1; Project_2; Project_3; Project_4;Project_N;
component_1;
component_2;
component_3;
component_4;
component_N;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly create the output from the dictionary without template:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({k: {k2: 'X' for k2 in l} for k, l in
                    project_components.items()})
```

If really you have a template with specific index/columns, you can [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) it:

```
out = out.reindex_like(template)
```

Output:

```
            Project_1 Project_2 Project_3 Project_4
component_1         X       NaN       NaN       NaN
component_2         X         X       NaN         X
component_3         X         X         X       NaN
component_4         X       NaN         X       NaN
```

If you really want to loop and modify the template:

```
template = pd.read_csv('Template.csv', sep=';', skipinitialspace=True,
                       index_col=0, dtype='str',
                       usecols=lambda x: not x.startswith('Unnamed:')
                       ).fillna('')

for k, l in project_components.items():
    if k not in template:
        print(f'"{k}" not found')
    template.loc[l, k] = 'X'
    
print(template)

template.to_csv('Output.csv', sep=';')
```

Output:

```
                    Project_1 Project_2 Project_3 Project_4 Project_N
Component / Project                                                  
component_1                 X                                        
component_2                 X         X                   X          
component_3                 X         X         X                    
component_4                 X                   X                    
component_N
```

CSV:

```
Component / Project;Project_1;Project_2;Project_3;Project_4;Project_N
component_1;X;;;;
component_2;X;X;;X;
component_3;X;X;X;;
component_4;X;;X;;
component_N;;;;;
```

*Note. I am assuming here that `Component / Project` is the **index**.*

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but I have to put it in the file from template

Comment: @macder I added an part about that in my answer, using `reindex_like`. Can you provide a reproducible example for the template? (as CSV or DataFrame)

Comment: sorry for long reply, I added my csv template

Comment: btw I tested your snippet and it looks like what I need, but I need your help to adapt it to use a csv file as a template

Comment: I think you just need to use `index_col=0` in `read_csv`

Comment: `FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value 'X' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
   template.loc[l, k] = 'X'` this error appears

Comment: And second question, how I can write result to the template file?

Comment: Check the update

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to be working as expected